# Unable to use SFTP via FileZilla?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssl, sftp

I created a Linux VM on Microsoft Azure via this blog [Creating secure Linux VMs in Azure with SSH key pairs](https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2013/06/secure-linux-vms-with-ssh-certificates/)

In summary it simply says:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout filename.key -out filename.pem`

After that we have to upload our `.pem` file for our Linux VM

[image: i uploaded filename.pem file]

After that, whenever I want to ssh into my vm, all I've to do is this:

`ssh -i .ssh/filename.key user@subdomain.cloudapp.net`

and I'm able to get inside my Linux VM, but I'm unable to use FileZilla to transfer file, I tried adding the `filename.key` file in FileZilla sftp settings but it is not accepting. No error just file open dialog closes without any error whatsoever.

I would really love if anyone can tell how can I connect via FileZilla. What I'm doing wrong, or some steps I've missed?

Answer (score -1):

As I see, you deployed your VM is Azure Service Manager (ASM) mode also know as classical mode. That means you are using Cloud Service and Azure Load Balancer.

The cloud service is accessed using a VIP (Load Balancer), while the individual VMs are normally accessed using VIP:. By assigning an Instance Level IP to a specific VM, that VM can be accessed directly using that IP address.

I think that should solve your problem :-)

All details to define an Instance Level IP on a VM : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

Regards

Stanislas

Comment: I don't see how this answer is supposed to help converting a pem file to a format supported by filezilla.

Comment: Oups my mistake. I misread the question. Sorry :-|